# PHP Match the entire word

Tags: php

I have a list of bad words in the database. Everytime a user submit a comment, a function goes through the entire list of bad words and replace each word with ***

```
  $query  = "SELECT * FROM bad_words ORDER BY id ASC";
  $result = mysql_query($query);    
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
   $word =  $row['word'];
   $replacement =  "***";

      $userInput = str_replace(" $word ", $replacement." ", $userInput);
  }
```

The problem is that str_replace does not work properly. For instance, "associated" will become "***ociated". I have also tried to use this preg_replace

```
$userInput = preg_replace("|\\b$\word\\b|i",$replacement,$userInput);
```

but it is not working for some reason. Some of the bad words in the database contains characters like
 `@ | , ! * ) . ^ ' ( @`

my guess is that these characters are causing preg_replace to fail. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside issues of whether this is a good idea, implementation is pretty simple:

```
$userInput = preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote($word, '/') . '\b/i', $replacement, $userInput);
```

You can probably also improve performance by using a single replacement:

```
$words = array();
$replacement =  "***";
$query  = "SELECT * FROM bad_words ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $words[] =  preg_quote($row['word'], '/');
} 

$userInput = preg_replace('/\b(' . implode('|', $words) . ')\b/i', $replacement, $userInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things:

- Your regex contained a `$` where `\b` would suffice. Also two backslashes aren't necessary.
- To match arbitrary characters in the words, apply `preg_quote()` first.
- You should assemble a complete list of badwords instead of iterating over them, else preg_replace is indeed slower than str_replace.

Try with:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     $words[] = $row["word"];
}

$words = array_map("preg_quote", $words);

preg_replace(":\b(" . implode("|", $words) . ")\b:i", ...);
```

Comment: Without a second argument, `preg_quote` will not escape the delimiter (`/` in this case).

Comment: @eyelidlessness Interesting and non-obvious. Avoided with quirky pcre enclosings above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$words = array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))) {
    $words[] =  '#\b' + preg_quote($row['word']) + '\b#i'; // escape special regex characters
}

$userInput = preg_replace($words, '***', $userInput);
```

`preg_replace` can take an array of expressions to search for.

Reference: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)